# jQuery autocomplete works only on the first row of the table

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have a modal button inside the table for each row which is an edit button and inside the modal, there is the autocomplete query from the database.

Issue: The (jQuery) auto-complete works only for the first row of the table. It doesn't work for the next row and so on.

This is my script:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $(document).on('keydown', '.second', function() {

        var id = this.id;
        var splitid = id.split('_');
        var index = splitid[2];

        $('#' + id).autocomplete({
            source: function(request, response) {
                $.ajax({
                    url: "getDetails.php",
                    type: 'post',
                    dataType: "json",
                    data: {
                        search: request.term,
                        request: 1
                    },
                    success: function(data) {
                        response(data);

                    }
                });
            },
            select: function(event, ui) {
                $(this).val(ui.item.label); // display the selected text
                var userid = ui.item.value; // selected id to input

                $.ajax({
                    url: 'getDetails.php',
                    type: 'post',
                    data: { userid: userid, request: 2 },
                    dataType: 'json',
                    success: function(response) {

                        var id = response[0]['id'];
                        var biddernumber = response[0]['biddernumber'];
                        var fb_id = response[0]['fb_id'];

                        document.getElementById('fb_id_' + index).value = fb_id;
                        document.getElementById('biddernumber_' + index).value = biddernumber;

                    }
                });
                return false;
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Everything works fine, the only thing I need is to make it work on all rows.

Comment: Are you sure all your elements of class ```.second``` have a unique id?

Comment: You might have to add the HTML part of your code as well so we can see what's happening.